# Changing the visibility scope of parent methods in child classes

Tags: php, methods, parent-child, visibility, extends

I've got a `Validator` class and a `UserValidator` class which extends from it.

My `Validator` has a public method `setRule(...)` with public visibility.

When I extend from it I want to change the visibility of the `setRule(...)` parent method to private/protected **within** the child so that it's only visible for the child and no outsiders can call this method **from** the child.

Is that possible? If so, how could I achieve it?

Comment: Use `protected` visibility rather than `public`

Comment: But that means, when my `Validator` class is used the `setRule()` method can't be accessed, because the method will then only be visible to the class itself and it's children only.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that's what you were asking for

Comment: No, you can't arbitrarily change visibility of methods on circumstance... though Reflection can simulate this, it's a dirty hack if you need to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an architectural point of view this is not recommended. As already stated in the comments the clean way would be to set your method to `protected` so only children can access it.

I cannot think of a single use case that would put me in the need to call a public method on a parent class but where I am not allowed to call it on the child class.

That's against the Open/Closed principle. Classes should be open for extension, but not for modification.

Since that was not the question I'll provide a way how that can be achieved though. But note:

- This method makes use of an extra class which will be responsible for the instantiation
- It's a hack. This solution will not make use of PHP's native language features when throwing accessibility errors.

First let's define the classes you already had

```
<?php

class Validator {

    public function setRule()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }

}

class UserValidator extends Validator {

    public $prop = 'PROPERTY';

}
```

There's nothing special here. So let's go on and create a custom exception class for the visibility error.

```
<?php

class MethodNotAccessibleException extends Exception {}
```

This exception will be thrown when we try to invoke a "pseudo-private" method on the child class.

Now we want to create the Class that will be responsible for instantiating your child class. It is basically just a wrapper that defines a `lock` property which holds method names that should not be accessible.

```
<?php

class PrivateInstanceCreator {

    protected $reflectionClass;
    protected $lock = [];
    protected $instance;

    public function __construct($classname, $args = []) 
    {
        // We'll store an instance of the reflection class
        // and an instance of the real class
        $this->reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($classname);
        $this->instance = $this->reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs($args);
        return $this;
    }

    // The lock method is able to make a method on the
    // target class "pseudo-private"
    public function lock($method)
    {
        $this->lock[] = $method;
        return $this;
    }

    // Some real magic is going on here
    // Remember. This class is a wrapper for the real class
    // if a method is invoked we look for the method
    // in the real instance and invoke it...
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        // ... but as soon as this method is defined as
        // locked, we'll raise an exception that the method
        // is private
        if(in_array($method, $this->lock))
        {
            $reflectionMethod = $this->reflectionClass->getMethod($method);
            if($reflectionMethod->isPublic())
                throw new MethodNotAccessibleException('Method: __' . $method . '__ is private and could not be invoked');
        }

        return call_user_func_array([$this->instance, $method], $args);
    }

    // The same goes for properties
    // But in this case we'll do no protection
    public function __get($prop)
    {
        return $this->instance->{$prop};
    }

}
```

Our final step is the instantiation.

```
<?php

$userValidator = new PrivateInstanceCreator('UserValidator', []);
$userValidator->lock('setRule');

$userValidator->setRule(); //Will throw an exception
```

Instead of instantiating the class directly we'll do it by using our custom wrapper class. 
Of course you could handle it in the child class itself, but that's a way to accomplish your task without touching the classes directly.

Having said that, **it is still a dirty hack whose usage should be avoided if possible**. If you would instantiate the child class directly the inherited methods would still be public.

So if a developer has no knowlege about the wrapper class he'll have a hard time to figure out how to instantiate the child class properly.

**Update:**

To make the child class uninstantiable directly you can set the constructor to `private` and call `newInstanceWithoutConstructor()` from the reflection class, which is even dirtier, since that would make [Dependency Injection](http://www.phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection) for the class completely impossible. I'm just mentioning it for completenesses sake. **Usage is still not recommended**