# Child class making inherited methods private

Tags: php, class, inheritance, private, public

So, basically, I have class `B` and `C`, whose parent is `class A`.
`Class A` has public method `set()`. But I want method `set()` to be private in class `B` and public in class `C`, so you can call it from instances of class `C` and you can't call it from instances of class `B`.
*Is it possible in PHP?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the visibility scope of parent methods in child classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426136/changing-the-visibility-scope-of-parent-methods-in-child-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The theory is that you should be able to use instances of a sub-class anywhere you could use instances of the parent, without knowing which you have.

If class A has a public method `foo`, I should be able to call `$a->foo()` for any value where `$a instanceof A` is true.

If the sub-class B makes this method private, I can't make the call.

The fancy name for this is the Liskov Substitution Principle.

You are, however, free to make the method behave how you like, so could for instance throw an Exception in class B - but make sure to always catch it somewhere.